# Converting a SQL query with group by into LINQ query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm stuggling to replicate a SQL query into LINQ.
Can any one help?

SQL:

```
 SELECT tblInvoice.lngID AS InvoiceID,
                tblInvoice.dtTimeStamp AS InvoiceDate,
                tblInvoice.strReference,
                tblInvoice.fltTotalValue,
                max(Project.ProjectID) AS ProjectID,
                max(Project.ProjectName) AS ProjectName,
                max(Project.Location) AS ProjectLocation
        FROM    tblInvoice INNER JOIN
                tblInvoiceLine ON tblInvoice.lngID = tblInvoiceLine.lngInvoiceID 
        WHERE   (tblInvoice.intStatus != 0)
        AND     (tblInvoice.lngPersonID = @PersonID)
        GROUP BY tblInvoice.lngID, tblInvoice.dtTimeStamp, strReference, fltTotalValue
        ORDER BY tblInvoice.lngID DESC
```

LINQ so far:

```
var invoices = from inv in db.TblInvoices
    join invLine in db.TblInvoiceLines on inv.LngID equals invLine.LngInvoiceID
    where inv.IntStatus != 0
    where inv.LngPersonID == personID
    group inv by  new {inv.LngID,inv.DtTimeStamp,inv.StrReference,inv.FltTotalValue} into newInv
```

Part of the problem is that I want to do a

```
select new Invoice(){
}
```

and build up my custom Invoice object but, I cant see any of the properties in newInv.

Can any one advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time for a full answer now, but:

- To get at properties of the key, use `newInv.Key.StrReference` etc
- To get at aggregates (e.g. max values) use `newInv.Max(x => x.ProjectId)` etc

Hopefully that'll be enough to get you going. Basically, `newInv` will be a *group* of entries, with an associated *key* (which is what you grouped by).

Comment: Of course the other option is to do a simple LINQ query then do a invoices.GroupBy(x => new { x.InvoiceID, x.InvoiceDate, x.Reference, x.TotalValue });